PHPUnit test using mockery is failing to intercept a method call on a mocked class
Here is my PHPUnit test (PHPUnit 10.5.2 Mockery 1.6.11)
    public function testMergedDocumentsWithSuccessfulInit() {
        $params = new \Buan\Request\Parameters([], [], [], []);
        $mockAdminView = m::mock(AdminView::class);

        // The mocking of init method will consider the inheritance from Ias\AdminController.
        $controller = m::mock('DocumentsController', [$params])
            ->makePartial()
            ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();

        // Mock the 'init' method which is inherited from Ias\AdminController
        $controller->shouldReceive('init')
            ->with($mockAdminView)
            ->andReturn(true)
            ->once(); // Ensure the init method is mocked to return true once

        echo "Mock setup complete, testing init call\n";
        $initResult = $controller->init($mockAdminView); // This should print true as the init method is mocked
        echo "init called, result: " . ($initResult ? "true" : "false") . "\n";

        // Execute the mergedDocuments method and check the result
        $result = $controller->mergedDocuments();

This is the start of the method I'm testing on my DocumentsController:
    public function mergedDocuments(): AdminView
    {
        // Init
        $view = new AdminView();
        $initResult = $this->init($view);
        if (!$initResult) {
            return $view;
        }

The 'init' method is defined in the AdminController which the DeveloperController extends e.g.
class DocumentsController extends Ias\AdminController
The DocumentsController is in the global namespace while the AdminController is in Ias (not sure if this is relevant).
Whatever I set "->andReturn(...)" to, the return $view is always reached i.e. the 'init' method is not being intercepted and runs as normal, always returning false.
protected function init(AdminView $view, bool $bypassAuthCheck = false): bool
My question, is why is the init method not being intercepted?
I was expecting by setting the 'andReturn' to false that the early return would not be reached in my mergeDocuments method.

I noticed in my IDE when I hovered over the 'init' function it said: "Member has protected visibility but can be accessed "__call" magic call method".  I updated my test as follows and this worked:
    public function MergedDocumentsWithFailedInit()
{
    $params = new \Buan\Request\Parameters([], [], [], []);

    // Since DocumentsController extends Ias\AdminController, create a mock of DocumentsController.
    // The mocking of init method will consider the inheritance from Ias\AdminController.
    $controller = m::mock('DocumentsController', [$params])
        ->makePartial()
        ->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods();

    // Mock the behavior of the __call method to delegate calls to init
    $controller->shouldReceive('__call')
        ->with('init', m::on(function ($args) {
            return count($args) == 1 && $args[0] instanceof AdminView;
        }))
        ->andReturnUsing(function ($method, $args) use ($controller) {
            return $controller->init(...$args);
        });

    // Mock the behavior of the init method to always return true
    $controller->shouldReceive('init')
        ->andReturn(false);

    $initResult = $controller->init($mockAdminView);

    // Execute the mergedDocuments method and check the result
    $result = $controller->mergedDocuments();
    $this->assertInstanceOf(AdminView::class, $result);
}

